# Why do I need to add 44 to UITextView frame height?

Tags: height, uilabel, uitextview, cgrectmake

I'm trying to change the height of a UITextView dynamically:

```
... UITextView* textView; ...

CGRect textViewNewFrame = CGRectMake(textView.frame.origin.x, textView.frame.origin.y, textView.frame.size.width, 130);
textView.frame = textViewNewFrame;
```

In IB, I have a UIButton top-aligned with my UITextView.  The UIButton is 130px high; the UITextView is, say, 150px high.

If I run the code above, the UITextView ends up 44px too short.  I have to change my CGRectMake line to end,

```
..., 130 + 44);
```

However, if in IB I 'hard-code' the height of the UITextView to 130px, the UIButton and UITextView are rendered both top- and bottom-aligned (they are both the same height).

So when changing the UITextView's frame's height dynamically I have to add 44, but not when 'statically' setting its height via IB.

Oddly, UILabel doesn't misbehave like this (I don't have to add 44px when dynamically resizing).

I know that 44 is a magic number in IB (the height of the nav bar etc) but why do I need to add it?  Am I missing something/doing something wrong, or is this just an anomaly?  I'm concerned that this must be such a common operation and yet I can't find anyone else asking the same question and coming to the same conclusion.